# How to store users with Unique Email in Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identity

I want to force Identity to only store users with an unique email, otherwise don't allow it to register, and then recover the exception or error when i iterate through the errors of the result of the `CreateAsync` method. So **How do i do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for `RequireUniqueEmail` is false. You can overwrite it with true to enforce unique email.

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    //add this option to identity configuration
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

});
```

Comment: Do i need add a migration or something? I tried your code and didn't work, maybe because i already have an 2 users with the same email.

Comment: I am not exactly sure about the migration. This is what I have in my project to enforce unique email. Can you try deleting the duplicate email users and try adding them back?

Comment: The migration isn't necessary I just deleted the duplicate email users and then it worked.